# Why am I losing cached network passwords after a restart of Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, passwords

The passwords cached for Network shares on other computers and applications like MSN Live, MS Outlook, Sharepoint portal, Outlook Webmail, etc are lost when I reboot my computer, which runs on Vista.

I always check the Remember password checkbox in applications/login dialogs where ever prompted.

I cannot imagine of a third party program that may clean up this on system restart/shutdown.

Any idea, as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one place to check at least -- maybe it's the trouble-maker for you:

Run gpedit.msc (you may have to 'Run As Administrator').

Look under Computer Configuration-> Windows Settings-> Security Settings-> Local Policies-> Security Options.

Find "Network access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication", ensure it's set to "Disabled".

Comment: It is disabled indeed!!! :-(